# Can't read rssfeed from link because of xml error

Tags: c#, xml-parsing

"http://lankadeepa.lk/index.php/maincontroller/breakingnews_rss"

this is a rssfeed link of a breaking news site.. I want to get links of the latest news from it. Here is the code I tried.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        XmlDocument lankadeepafeed = new XmlDocument();

        try
        {
            lankadeepafeed.Load("http://lankadeepa.lk/index.php/maincontroller/breakingnews_rss/");
            XmlNode page = lankadeepafeed.DocumentElement;

            XmlNodeList newslinks = page.SelectNodes("//link");

            foreach (XmlNode newslink in newslinks)
            {
                textBox1.Text += newslink.OuterXml;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            textBox1.Text += ex.Message;
        }
    }
```

I have tried this code with another rssfeed and it works without errors.. But with this rss here is the exception I got:

> The "channel" start tag on line 10 position 6 does not match the end tag of "admin:generatoragent". Line 184, position 11

I think the problem is not with my code. What am I supposed to do to prevent or skip this error ?

Comment: Looks like the line: <admin:generatorAgent rdf:resource="http://www.codeigniter.com/" /> has a closing forward slash. it's not perfect but you could try reading the xml as just text and removing this "/". then loading it as XML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `XML` returned is not in a correct format.

It has self-closing tag `<admin:generatoragent>` at line `19`.

and then a closing tag `</admin:generatoragent>` at line `184`.

Now the solution is to consider your `xml` is an string, and delete the `/` of self-closing tag on line `19`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the XMLReaderSettings to be as forgiving as posibble?

The possible settings of the XmlReaderSettings
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Xml.XmlReaderSettings_properties(v=vs.110).aspx

How it's implemented
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/318876/Using-the-XmlReader-class-with-Csharp

Comment: is it necessary to use xmlreader ? Isnt there anyway to skip that error without using an xmlreader ?